# Valid case error after Idris hint

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I am attempting to prove the following:

```
d_3 : (lcm (S k) (S j) = 0) -> Void
```

I ask idris to generate function body skeleton and get

```
d_3 : (lcm (S k) (S j) = 0) -> Void
d_3 prf = ?d_3_rhs
```

So far so good, but then I ask for case match on `prf` and end up with

```
d_3 : (lcm (S k) (S j) = 0) -> Void
d_3 Refl impossible
```

To me that seems somewhat reasonable, however when I try to type check I get the error:

```
d_3 Refl is a valid case
```

What does it mean? How should I fix it? And why does Idris recommend something it later complains about?

Comment: It's interesting that your proof works if the statement is reformulated like this: `d_3 : Not (lcm (S k) (S j) = Z)`.

Comment: This is probably related to the fact that [`lcm` is partial](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L394), so the typechecker is not normalizing its applications. But then why does it work with `Not (lcm (S k) (S j) = 0)`...?

Comment: I believe in the case with `(lcm (S k) (S j) = 0) -> Void` you observe an instance of [#3185](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/3185) bug.

Comment: @Cactus Looks like the issue with `Not` arises because of [#2821](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2821) bug. It easy to redefine `lcm` as a total function, using the `divNatNZ` function. And then "prove" `Void` like this: `lcmZero' : Not (lcm' k j = Z)
lcmZero' Refl impossible

lcmVoid' : Void
lcmVoid' = lcmZero' {k = Z} {j = Z} Refl`

Comment: So could this be an actual bug in idris?